# Added memory does nothing to performance

Tags: imac

iMac, 27" screen.  Came with 4 gig of memory.  I never used all 4 gig until I started using IMovie.  Bought 8 gig extra memory, now have total of 12 gig.  Nothing speeded up at all.  When monitoring the memory, it seems that I'm always using over 8 gig and can only clean up the memory to about 6 gig.  How did I ever get by with 4 gig?  Nothing adds up.

Comment: Stop trying to 'clean up' the memory. It knows far better than you or I what it needs to work with. Empty memory is wasted memory. If adding RAM didn't speed the machine up then your bottleneck is either the CPU or your HD speed. Swapping to an SSD would be next thing to do.

Comment: Unless you post more detailed information related to processes running, memory usage and even hard disk usage you will not be able to diagnose the issue. You may have 32Gb of RAM but your hard drive may be so slow when processing the video files making it the bottleneck, other thing may be the new memory is not compatible or with the exact same specs as the old one and it may be slowing instead of speeding it up, have you tried with just the new 8Gb of RAM?

Answer (score 1):

The (good) old days where you had to manage your RAM usage are history.

Apple OS X does that for you.

Keeping free RAM is thing of the past. It did not make sense anyway to keep unused RAM.

The OS X manages the RAM for maximum efficiency, and speed.

In doing so it will load the RAM up to what is needed.

If your system appears to be slow, it is usually not the RAM, but some process eating up the CPU.

You can look up in the Activity monitor to see what is it.